# Operation category READ is not supported in state standby when using distcp

Tags: hadoop

Hi when i try to move data using the hadoop distp command i get

```
ERROR tools.DistCp: Exception encountered

org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.StandbyException): Operation category READ is not supported in state standby
```

anyone encountered the same issue and resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means the namenode you've configured for the command is in standby mode, and is not the active one. You'll need to use a nameservice HDFS address if you have a Namenode HA configuration